# Border-left-color not working in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to change `border-left-color` with this script, but i keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -`.

Isn't border-left-color supported?

**Javascript**

```
function logoChange() { 
var description = new Array ();
description[0] = "images/logo/blue.png";
description[1] = "images/logo/green.png";
description[2] = "images/logo/orange.png";
description[3] = "images/logo/purple.png";
description[4] = "images/logo/red.png";
description[5] = "images/logo/yellow.png";
var size = description.length;
var x = Math.floor(size*Math.random());
document.getElementById('logo').src=description[x];

var colors = ['#20A3DC', '#72BF48', '#F58623', '#AF3292', '#EA352E', '#FED608'];

var thecolor = colors[x];

$('li span').css({color: thecolor});


$(".orbit-container .orbit-next span").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        border-left-color: thecolor  //border-left-color
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css({
        border-left-color: 'black'  //border-left-color
    });
});


$("a").hover(function () {
    $(this).css({
        color: thecolor
    });
}, function () {
    $(this).css({
        color: 'black'
    });
});

}

window.onload=logoChange;
```

**Error message**

[image]

Comment: `"border-left-color":` or `borderLeftColor:`

Comment: Just curious, which IDE are you using? It looks useful.

Comment: @AycanYaşıt That just looks like Chrome's dev tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using quotes around css property and static value while assigning.it should be:

```
$(this).css({
    'border-left-color': thecolor  //border-left-color
});
```

Comment: maybe remove the quotes on 'thecolor' because it is a variable

Comment: @Haroldchen: Thanks. That is the reason i have used term static value.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

add quotes:

```
$(this).css({
    'border-left-color': thecolor
});
```

"snakename" the attribute:

```
$(this).css({
    borderLeftColor: thecolor
});
```

or even, as you only have one property to change, simplify with:

```
$(this).css('border-left-color', thecolor);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you come to setting CSS properties using jquery, you always have to go with camelcasing. Hence `border-bottom` becomes `borderBottom` and `border-left-color` becomes `borderLeftColor`

Answer (score 0):

You have to enclose it within a string lieral:

```
... $(this).css({
     'border-left-color':  theColor
    });
..
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("selector").css('border-left', 'solid 1px red');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9Q9Vm/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can go with two options.

#### Quotes:

```
$(this).css({
    'border-left-color': '#AAA'
});
```

#### CamelCase:

```
$(this).css({
    borderLeftColor: '#AAA'
});
```